# How to Suport Multi Touch on My Android Application?

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout, multi-touch

I'm having some difficulties on my android application. I have some chronometers (4 or 5) and I need to be able to touch more than one of then and record the time. 
eg.:
When i touch two of the chronometers both of then should display the same time.

I tried putting the chronometers on a listview, and also as table rows in a tablelayout. On both situations I'm able to record times if a touch chronometers one at a time but when i touch two at the same time only one of then recordes the event.

I don't know if it's necessary but i have this on my manifest file:

```
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand"
    android:required="false"
/>
```

Any one knows how to fix it? Do I have to set some configuration allowing multitouch for my aplication?
(I'm working on android 3.1, if there's a solution that works only on 3.x i'm ok with that)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: check this link,
{ http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763 }

Comment: I thought there was an easier solution, but I think that's the only way to go. It helped a lot understanding the touch event!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to multi-touch as well. I was direct to check out the link krio provided and I also found this link helpful in understanding it:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: +1 Upvote for a better source. By the way Android's mainheads should simplify these things for developers.